# Fabricjs- large canvas zoom, pan and performance

Tags: javascript, canvas, zooming, fabricjs, pan

I'm an intern currently working on a browser-based graphic editor- similar to paint but more specific in terms of functionality. I'm using fabric.js and struggling with a task I've been given, mostly because I'm new to this technology.

The situation is: 
a)I have a 3000x6000 canvas 
b)I have a lot of custom objects with a lot of actions on mouse over or on mouse click set to them
c)I have the canvas inside a div which limits our view of the canvas to around 500x1000 pixels 
d)I've written a zoom functionality which calls the method setZoom() and works as intended and all listeners work as intended.

The problem is:
a) I have to implement a scrolling functionality which works like a hand: on mousedown i begin to drag the canvas, and on every mousemove i scroll the canvas div for the appropriate amount of pixels. 
b) This functionality works as intended, but when the canvas gets zoomed in, i can't scroll to the end of the canvas- and when it gets zoomed out i can scroll over the canvas.

I've been trying to get this to work so that i can always scroll to the borders of the canvas and not beyond them- but I've failed to do that. I tried to use relativePan and limit the borders but it hasn't succeeded- maybe i do not know enough of FabricJS.

Does anyone have any advice that could help me solve this problem? Any help would be priceless for me and my career. 
Thank you very much in advance.

P.S.
I've also encountered an issue with performance when creating a 3000x3000 canvas- the whole canvas was lagging like crazy, but when I switched to 3000x6000 it worked just fine. Do you have any ideas why?

UPDATE 1: Here is the link to the JSFiddle-I've forked someone's polygon draw fiddle and added my test case. To recreate, please click around 15 times on a canvas and try to move around the mouse for a while. Then, change canvas width in HTML code to 3000, so that the canvas is square, and then do the same. You should notice, than on a 3000x3000 canvas sometimes lags unexpectedly. 
`JSFiddle:`(http://jsfiddle.net/9wo6ez61/2/)

Comment: Without code it's difficult to diagnose, but are you adjusting the mouse position reported by the browser into "zoomed space"? The browser never reports scaled/zoomed coordinates.

Comment: Regarding performance: All Fabric objects are "managed" (respond to events, auto-redraw themselves, etc) and therefore incur bigger performance hits than un-managed drawings. And the larger the canvas the more effort it takes to redraw and the more performance lags (A 3000x3000 canvas is very large). So it's likely that your "large canvas + many custom objects + many event listeners per object" is a design problem (flaw) that will naturally cause performance lags.

Comment: Oh so you are that 19yold boy that wrote me. I will try to help as soon as i can. very busy now. Could you start a little snippet here with a basic fabricJs canvas? i do not think you should use the scrolling div at all.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the problem with canvas proportions- the thing is that on a basic JSFiddle it's not a problem, but on our environment it is a large issue- i'll be trying to find the causeof the problem and publish it here. The question I opened actually has a lot of features and things that it touches on, i'll soon post some updates here.

Comment: I've updated the test case, try to recreate the issue using my guidelines.